# Unable to get the onchange function activated

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, jscript

I am not able to make the following code work....

```
<H3>Select your Office Location:</H3>
<SELECT id=selOption onchange=goToUrl(this.value)><OPTION selected>--Select--</OPTION>
<OPTION value=/sites/rnd2/products/ITC/operations/Lists/802%20%20Australia%20Barton%20survey/NewForm.aspx>802 - Australia, Barton</OPTION>
<OPTION value=/sites/rnd2/products/ITC/operations/Lists/852%20%20Australia%20Melbourne%20survey/NewForm.aspx>852 - Australia, Melbourne survey</OPTION>
<OPTION value=/sites/rnd2/products/ITC/operations/Lists/855%20%20Australia%20North%20Ryde%20%20Survey/NewForm.aspx>855 - Australia, North Ryde Survey</OPTION>
<OPTION value=/sites/rnd2/products/ITC/operations/Lists/864%20%20Australia%20Applecross%20%20Survey/NewForm.aspx>864 - Australia, Applecross Survey</OPTION>
...
</select>
```

It keeps giving me "Object expected" error.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You have to set " on each HTML attribute like this:

```
<SELECT id="selOption" onchange="goToUrl(this.value)">
```

Comment: You have to set the " Chars on every Attribute except flags like `selected`. If that doesn't help please show me the goToUrl function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `goToUrl()` has to be specified before you're using it:

```
<script>
    function goToUrl(url) {
        window.location = url;
    }
</script>    
<SELECT id="selOption" onchange="goToUrl(this.value)">
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qNpd/2/).

*Also, your html attribute values should be enclosed in quotes.*

Comment: A message box popups up giving the URL. However, I want to redirect it to the URL once the option is selected.

Comment: @RahulBasu Yes, it was there to illustrate my point. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @RahulBasu Well click on the check mark next to the answer (on the left, where the votes are).